# How to apply Windows Phone Toolkit effects to controls?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

we can apply some effects of [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) to form like this:

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

But How can I apply it to a special control. like images or grid?

Answer (score 1):

For animating a control you should use a Storyboard!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.aspx
(take a look at the examples at the bottom of the page)

EDIT:
The WP tookit seems to include a property for that: `toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex`

You just need to set this property for each element to the number relating to the order. So 0 is the first one, 1 the second and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try to put this in APP.XAML.CS under the **NavigationFrame** code base